# No color on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can't seem to figure out why the remaining 3 tabs don't have colors when I hover my mouse. The first 3 are working properly but the remaining 3 are not. I only made adjustments on their margins and nothing more. I just like to put code on my Blogger blog because its quite helpful. Below are the codes I'm having problems with. They are working on the console but when I put it on my blog the hover effect is not there.

```css
p {
  margin-top: -30px;
}

.ctc-txt.bg_ffffff.br6 {
  width: 642px;
  height: 200px;
}

.clr-txt {
  top: 160px;
}

.text-center.ct-case.mb10 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: right;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-left: 120px;
}

.counter {
  margin-left: -14px;
}

#copyStr {
  margin-left: 260px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

#text {
  top: -30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://rawgit.com/Dieffer/test1/master/mycss.css">
<form method="post" id="text" action="">
  <p class="">
    Type or Paste your text here to change text case
  </p>
  <div class="relative">
    <textarea class="ctc-txt bg_ffffff br6" name="form_content" id="form_content" onclick="cont()"> </textarea>
    <img class="clr-txt" onclick="resete()" src="https://smallseotools.com/asets/images/cleartext.svg">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 pn pt5 pb5">
    <div class="button_box h-a">
      <div class="counter">
        <label>Character Count: <span id="cc"> 0 </span></label>
        <label>- Word Count: <span id="wc"> 0 </span></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center ct-case mb10" id="ctc_button_box">
    <input name="toggle" class="button ctc-btn br6" type="button" id="toggle" value="tOGGLE cASE">
    <input name="sentence" class="button ctc-btn br6" type="button" id="sentence" value="Sentence case">
    <input name="lower" class="button ctc-btn br6" type="button" id="lower" value="lower case">
    <input name="" class="button ctc-btn br6" type="button" id="upper" value="UPPER CASE">
    <input name="capitalized" class="button ctc-btn br6" type="button" id="capitalized" value="Capitalize Word">
    <input name="alternating" class="button ctc-btn br6" type="button" id="alternating" value="aLtErNaTe cAsE">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: can you show some screenshot on your blog where it dont seem working because i run your code in my machine and its working properly

Comment: Your code is working fine. Check this https://codepen.io/mukesh_m4m/pen/JBdGJz?editors=1100

Comment: Seems to work, I made a code snippet from your own post so you can see it yourself. The example doesn't fully work as you have not posted your used JavaScript. But that's not in the scope of this question. So it might be some other CSS that's in your project that "overrules" the posted CSS.

Comment: Given that the code you've provided works (as you've confirmed and confirmed by comments) - there must be something different in your blog code/html/css.   Unfortunately, without that code, we can't really help you other than guessing.   Your best approach would be either to start with an empty file and build it up until you get the problem or remove code/html until you can find the issue.

Comment: Hi Ferdinand Co Receno, I run the code in my machine, it worked fine in my machine. I don't think there is any problem with the code.

Comment: Hello, these are the screenshots of the buttons: 
https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Wasz32cgGVQ/W0cOJp2CK9I/AAAAAAAADP0/hGmgWe-AQb4lqKODkYZaiwfSOYOf_nUHgCLcBGAs/s1600/sc1.jpg

Comment: The one's not working

https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-sWfmsu_LcX8/W0cOKeC8KHI/AAAAAAAADP4/GgNzIZi7E_sRH2Itf6a2KyCwGjckOHz3wCEwYBhgL/s1600/sc4.jpg

https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-gFzEWFy6Fuo/W0cOK9MV9NI/AAAAAAAADP8/sQDu-Oftjz49ML_-HE0qAwY9r0mm6zbrgCEwYBhgL/s1600/sc5.jpg

https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-sWfmsu_LcX8/W0cOKeC8KHI/AAAAAAAADP4/GgNzIZi7E_sRH2Itf6a2KyCwGjckOHz3wCEwYBhgL/s1600/sc4.jpg

Comment: https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-sWfmsu_LcX8/W0cOKeC8KHI/AAAAAAAADP4/GgNzIZi7E_sRH2Itf6a2KyCwGjckOHz3wCEwYBhgL/s1600/sc4.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to clean your browser-cache? 
Since the Code works just fine, maybe that could cause the problem.

Comment: I clean the cache and still the 3 tabs still not showing colors..I run it on 3 consoles and they work fine but not on Blogger page:( ...

Comment: I wonder why the first 3 buttons have nth-child() and the remaining 3 don't have.